# Java Commit HsqlDB

Tags: java, hsqldb

Try to perform a sql insert in java, but impossible to commit with hsqldb:

```
public class VehiculeDAO extends DAO<Vehicule> {

    public Vehicule create(int marque, int moteur, int prix, String nom) {

        System.out.println("\t marque:" + marque +"moteur:"+moteur+"prix:"+prix+"nom:"+nom); 

        Vehicule vehicule = new Vehicule();

        String query = " INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (0,4,100,'test2');";
        query += "commit;";

        try {
            connect.setAutoCommit(true);
            ResultSet result = this.connect.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE).executeQuery(" INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (0,4,100,'test3')" );
            connect.commit();
            result.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return;
        return vehicule;
  }
```

Insert is done but not committed.
Any idea to debug it?

As requested, short description of application :

`HsqldbConnection`:

```
public class HsqldbConnection {

    private HsqldbConnection() {
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // ...
```

`TestDAO`:

```
public class TestDAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        DAO<Vehicule> vehiculedao = DAOFactory.getVehiculeDAO();
        Vehicule vehicule = vehiculedao.create( 0 ,5, 100, "test");

        // ...
```

`DAOFactory`:

```
public class DAOFactory {
    protected static final Connection conn = HsqldbConnection.getInstance();

    public static DAO getMarqueDAO(){
        return new MarqueDAO(conn);
    }

    public static DAO getVehiculeAO(){
        return new MarqueDAO(conn);
    }   
}
```

Commit command must be inserted in class `VehiculeDAO`, I guess?

`Test commit`:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

```
  String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:hsqldb/database/VEHICULE";
  String user = "";
  String passwd = "";

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

  Statement state = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
  PreparedStatement prepare = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO VEHICULE (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (0,4,100,'testcommit')");


  prepare.executeUpdate();

  conn.commit();

  prepare.close();

  state.close();         
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: You are setting auto commit to true, calling `Connection.commit()` under those circumstances is an error, as the driver will commit automatically after the statement execute. Your problem is probably elsewhere. Please create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i Agree, but not find where is the issue, hereunder a minimal presentation of package

Comment: private HsqldbConnection() {
  try {
   connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
                        
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: public class TestDAO {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
  
  DAO<Vehicule> vehiculedao = DAOFactory.getVehiculeDAO();
       Vehicule vehicule = vehiculedao.create( 0 ,5, 100, "test");
       Vehicule vehicule2 = vehiculedao.find("tout");

Comment: Don't post code in comments, **edit** your question.

Comment: Code has been re-edited in Question.

Comment: I 've performed a commit test class, see upper, with executeUpdate(). But no commit command is done. I really don't see why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use statement.executeUpdate() instead of statement.executeQuery().

Comment: Nope, I have ever tried executeUpdate(), but same issue -> no commit has been performed on hsqldb DB.

Comment: I 've performed a commit test class, see upper, with executeUpdate(). But no commit command is done. I really don't see why ?